# How to split RX and TX bytes by process?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.
I know how to get the total number of bytes sent and received over the network this session, in Ubuntu 16.04 it is `/sys/class/net/*enp3s0*/statistics/rx_bytes` and `/tx_bytes`, but is there any way to get that split by process id?

I have written a front end for `netstat` (in wxPHP, see [screenshot](http://palloy.earth/netstat.GUI.screenshot.png)) and I want to display Current Bytes/second too, the idea being if I see some unusual traffic burst, I can tell where its endpoints are.